# Extracting certain parts of an email using Python (Regex)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a program that will import messages from a particular folder in Outlook and then extract certain parts in the email.

The emails are of the form:
Dear Mr.X,

{Lines of Text} See below.

Client: Company X

Fund: ABCD

Size:

Thanks,
Sam

The code i have so far is:

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(4)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.body
```

Can someone help me with the code using regex to extract all pieces of information in the email that follows the ":" such as Client:CompanyX, etc.?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Where to find text snippets like this one, Ruben?

Comment: @ChristianBerendt don't remember where I got this one, but you can copy it if you want.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated! Im new to python and am not sure how to go about this part of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `regex` just [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the text on the `:` and get the last element:

```
In [5]: s = "Client: Company X"

In [6]: print s.split(":")[-1]
Company X
In [7]: s = "Fund: ABCD"

In [8]: print s.split(":")[-1]
 ABCD
```

Comment: I need the program to sift through the email and find "Client:", "Fund:",etc. and then print whatever is following the ":"

Comment: loop over the lines and use  the `str.startswith`  method to find lines starting with  Client:,Fund: etc.. then use the split to get the info. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html #str.startswith